# Was the Latin word lucifer exchanged in Isaiah 14:12 for the Hebrew word Helel and do they, along with the Greek word phosperous mean morning star?

Tags: terminology

A knowledge of the Hebrew, Greek and Latin words used for english translation in the Old and New Testament. I've read conflicting information.

Comment: *[Phos-phoros](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/φωσφόρος#Etymology)* and *[luci-fer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lucifer#Latin)* both mean *light-bearer*, and have indeed been used by ancient [Greeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_(morning_star)) and [Romans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer#Roman_folklore_and_etymology) to refer to the morning star, the planet Venus. *[Shahar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahar_(god))* means *dawn*, and *[ben](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben)* is a Semitic patronymic.

Comment: The ending of *Helel* or *Halel* is a well-known Semitic [theonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_(deity)).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here... the original was Hebrew, so it didn't replace the Latin. Are you asking about the Septuagint and Vulgate translations?

Comment: See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/73972/is-the-root-chosen-for-translation-in-isaiah-1412-for-helel-%d7%94%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%9c-wrong-in-most

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew word הֵילֵל (*heilel*) occurs in Zechariah 11:2 and Ezekiel 21:12<sup>1</sup> where it is translated into Greek as ὀλολυξάτω and ὀλόλυξον, respectively, imperative conjugations of the onomatopoetic ὀλολύζω, which is translated into English by the verb “howl” or “wail.”<sup>2</sup>

[image: BDAG, p. 704, ὀλολύζω]

Coincidentally, Aquila in his more literal Greek translation<sup>3</sup> of the Hebrew scriptures translated the Hebrew הֵילֵל בֶּן־שָׁחַר (*heilel ben-shachar*) by ὀλολύζων υἱὸς ὄρθρου, which is translated into English as “[O’] howling/wailing son of dawn.”<sup>4</sup> Apparently Aquila interpreted הֵילֵל as a participle derived from the root יָלַל (*yalal*), “howl/wail,” rather than הָלַל (*halal*), “shine.” It is also noteworthy that the verb יָלַל occurs approximately 31 times in the Masoretic text, and 11 of those 31 instances occur in the Book of Isaiah.<sup>5</sup>

Of course, we can delve into various later commentaries to understand how others interpreted it, but why not the source himself? And by “source,” I am referring to the very person responsible for writing *lucifer* in the Vulgate, which of course found its way into the King James Version. That person would be Jerome.

Jerome wrote a commentary on the Book of Isaiah where he discusses the verse in question.<sup>6</sup>

> *(Isa. 14:12-14) Quomodo cecidisti de cælo, lucifer, qui mane oriebaris: corruisti in terram qui vulnerabas gentes: qui dicebas in corde tuo: In cælum ascendam, super sidera Dei exaltabo solium meum, sedebo in monte testamenti in lateribus Aquilonis; ascendam super altitudinem nubium, ero similis Altissimo.
>
>
> Pro eo quod nos interpretati sumus ob facilitatem intelligentiae: Quomodo cecidisti de cælo, lucifer, qui mane oriebaris, in Hebraico, ut **verbum** exprimamus **ad verbum**, legitur: Quomodo cecidisti de cælo, ulula fili diluculi.*

My best translation of his Latin passage:

> (Isa. 14:12-14) “How you have fallen from heaven, *lucifer* (Venus), you who used to appear early! How you have fallen upon the earth, you who wounded the nations! And you said in your heart, ‘I will ascend into heaven. I will exalt my throne above the stars of God. I will sit in the mountain of the covenant, upon the sides of the north. I will ascend above the height of the clouds; I will be like the Most High.’”
> For that which we had interpreted for ease of understanding, “How have you fallen from heaven, O’ Venus (*lucifer*), you who used to appear early,” in Hebrew, so that we may express it **word-for-word**,  it reads, “How you have fallen from heaven! Wail [*ulula*], son of dawn!”

So, this tells me that Jerome, who translated the Hebrew הֵילֵל בֶּן־שָׁחַר by *lucifer qui mane oriebaris* (“O’ Venus, you who used to appear early”), admitted that the Hebrew **literally** (i.e., *verbum ad verbum*) translated into Latin as *ulula fili diluculi*—and thus English as “Howl, son of dawn!”

Why, then, did Jerome translate the Hebrew into Latin as *lucifer qui mane oriebaris*? If Jerome admits that the Hebrew literally means *ulula fili diluculi* (“Howl, son of dawn!”), but nevertheless translates it as *lucifer qui mane oriebaris* (“O’ Venus, you who used to rise early”), it seems the only plausible explanation is that Jerome preferred to translate the Greek Septuagint rather than the Hebrew.

The Greek Septuagint has ὁ ἑωσφόρος ὁ πρωὶ ἀνατέλλων, “O’ Venus, who appeared early.” (Quite obvious, is it not?)

Both the Greek ἑωσφόρος and the Latin *lucifer* were used in early Latin and Greek writings in reference to what we refer to in English as the planet Venus.

Circero wrote,<sup>7</sup>

> *Infima est quinque errantium terraeque proxima stella Veneris, quae Φωσφόρος Graece, Lucifer Latine dicitur, cum antegreditur solem, cum subsequitur, Hesperus.*
>
> Lowest of the five wandering [stars] and nearest to the earth is the star of Venus, called in Greek Φωσφόρος and in Latin *Lucifer* only when it precedes the sun, [but] Hesperos when it follows [the sun].

Accordingly, both the Greek verb ἀνατέλλω<sup>8</sup> and the Latin verb *orior*<sup>9</sup> (from which *oriebaris* is conjugated) are also used in the sense of a celestial body (e.g., Venus) **appearing** in the sky.

[image]

Finally, both ἑωσφόρος and *lucifer* occur several times elsewhere in the Septuagint<sup>10</sup> and Vulgate,<sup>11</sup> respectively.

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Eze. 21:17 Masoretic text <sup>2</sup> BDAG, p. 704 <sup>3</sup> Silverstone, p. [156](https://books.google.com/books?id=bhYNAQAAIAAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>4</sup> Field, Vol. 2, p. [456](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft/page/456/mode/1up), Isa. 14:12 <sup>5</sup> Isa. 13:6, 14:12, 14:31, 15:2, 15:3, 16:7 (x2), 23:1, 23:6, 23:14, 52:5, 65:14 <sup>6</sup> Migne, PLM, Vol. 24, p. [165–166](https://books.google.com/books?id=mHTciI6-7dcC&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q&f=false), Vers. 12–14 <sup>7</sup> Cicero, *De Natura Deorum* (“On the Nature of the Gods”), 2.20.53 <sup>8</sup> LSJ, p. 123, ἀνατέλλω <sup>9</sup> Lewis & Short, p. [1279](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi/page/1279/mode/1up), *ŏrĭor* <sup>10</sup> ἑωσφόρος occurs in the LXX in 1 Sam. 30:17; Job 3:9, 11:17, 38:12, 41:18 (41:10 Masoretic); Psa. 110:3 (109:3 Masoretic) <sup>11</sup> *lucifer* occurs in the Vulgate in Job 11:17, 38:32; Psa. 110:3 (109:3 Masoretic); 2 Pet. 1:19 |

| References |
| --- |
| Arndt, William; Bauer, Walter; Danker, Frederick William. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature.* 3rd ed. Chicago: U of Chicago P, 2000. Eusebius Sophronius Hieronymus. [“Commentariorum in Isaiam Prophetam Libri Duodeviginti.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=mHTciI6-7dcC&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false) [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Latina.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mHTciI6-7dcC) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 24. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1865. Field, Frederick. [*Origenis Hexaplorum Quæ Supersunt; sive Veterum Interpretum Graecorum in Totum Vetus Testamentum Fragmenta.*](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft) Vol. 2. Oxonii: E Typographeo Clarendoniano, 1875. Lewis, Charlton T.; Short, Charles. [*Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon.*](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi) New York: American Book, 1879. Liddell, Henry George; Scott, Robert; et al. *A Greek-English Lexicon.* 9th ed. with revised supplement. Oxford: Clarendon, 1996. Silverstone, Alec Eli. [*Aquila and Onkelos.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bhYNAQAAIAAJ) Manchester: Manchester UP, 1931. |

Comment: Sheer excellence. A pleasure to see such succinct accuracy. (Up-voted +1).

Comment: Do any pre-Vulgate Vetus Latina (Old Latin) manuscripts use the word "lucifer" at Isaiae 14:12?